# Changes committed as wrong user? TortoiseSVN, Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

We've got a weird problem, it's been going on for a while - maybe a year.  For some users, the authentication seems to get corrupted and we'll check-in and it'll appear as another user. Specically, our "BuildMachine" account that runs in a back room, to make our "official" builds (it checks out a branch, builds, and checks-in the binaries).  Somehow, that account carries over into things that our team members check-in from our local workstations.

We've been through several revs of both TortoiseSVN and SVN itself - in fact, we moved from an older server running older versions of SVN+Apache, using SVN authentication.  Now we're on current SVN via VisualSVN server, using LDAP for authentication.  (totally different authentication, right?)  I figured for sure, this would "cure" this issue.  But nope...

- Our clients are all on TortoiseSVN 1.6.16, Subversion 1.6.17.
- The server is VisualSVN server, Version: 2.1.9
- Subversion command-line client (on the server) is 1.6.17

We have several (pretty extensive) pre-commit and post-commit hooks that audit against some corporate change/defect tracking systems, create code reviews, etc.. So that complicates things a bit.

I have no idea how things get this way, but the "cure", temporary as it is, is to clear the authentication data cache in Tortoise.  That seems weird because it's not as if I'd ever committed anything as "BuildMachine" from my PC. But clearing MY credentials will somehow magically get rid of BuildMachine. Weird.

Anybody know what can cause this?  I know there's a Tortoise 1.7 out now, but we're not ready to roll that out, and the release notes seem to indicate that it's kind of a big deal to "upgrade" all my local copies.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same problem after standing up a new Jenkins project - my local check-ins were credited to our nightly-build account.

From a command line prompt, run `svn auth` - it will show you all of the credentials for subversion. I found there was an entry for me, and also a similar entry for the nightly-build "user" I then used `svn auth --remove` with the offending user name. Next time I tried to do an svn operation, I had to log in, but no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen several people have strange issues with VisualSVN on Stackoverflow. The most recent [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909089/cant-commit-to-svn-server) someone recommended something called [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to debug the HTML traffic.

That might give you an idea what's messing up the authentication.

If you want to fix the authorship of your commits, you can use the `svn propset --reveprop` command to set the `svn:author` revision property for a particular revision. You'll have to enable the pre-revprop-change.sh hook because the default is to disallow revision property changes.

Comment: The problem pre-dates our move to VisualSVN, so I don't think that's it. Maybe though. I may resort to Fiddler2, but was hoping for a more definitive answer as to what causes the issue in the first place.  I've already enabled the properties change, and we can (when we remember to) edit the authorship right in Tortoise now.